# div showing up in the background

Tags: html, css, wordpress

trying to get this:
http://webdev.edulence.com/getchell/products-services/commercial-insurance/

to look like this:
http://getchellcompanies.com/products/commercial.html

for some reason, the shadow div at the bottom is showing up behind the wrapper, with a white background, despite the shadow appearing after the wrapper in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

`#shadow` is different in your CSS than the working page.

```
#shadow {
    margin: -50px 0pt 0pt -65px;
    top: 44px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

added the following  to footer.

```
#footer{  margin-top: 60px;}
```

and used the below styles for the shadow.

```
#shadow{
        background-image: url("images/dropShadow.png");
        height: 103px;
        position: absolute;width: 1121px;
        z-index: 1;
        clear: both;background-position: -15px 5px;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;margin-left: -40px;
        margin-top: -35px;
}
```